# Dual AMD EPYC 7742 cpus show only 255 threads

Tags: cpu

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a Supermicro Superserver.  Dual AMD EPYC 7742 cpus are installed on the server.   The results of a Geekbench 4 benchmark show 255 threads instead of the expected 256 threads. The results of lscpu, which are attached below, also show 255 threads.   Other Geekbench 4 benchmarks that are using Ubuntu 19.04 with dual AMD EPYC 7742 cpus show 256 threads.  Is there limitation with 18.04.3 that restricts the number of threads to 255?

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:         x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):       32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:           Little Endian
CPU(s):               256
On-line CPU(s) list:  0-254
Off-line CPU(s) list: 255
Thread(s) per core:   1
Core(s) per socket:   64
Socket(s):            2
NUMA node(s):         2
Vendor ID:            AuthenticAMD
CPU family:           23
Model:                49
Model name:           AMD EPYC 7742 64-Core Processor
Stepping:             0
CPU MHz:              1499.869
CPU max MHz:          2250.0000
CPU min MHz:          1500.0000
BogoMIPS:             4499.70
Virtualization:       AMD-V
L1d cache:            32K
L1i cache:            32K
L2 cache:             512K
L3 cache:             16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):    0-63,128-191
NUMA node1 CPU(s):    64-127,192-254
Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `lscpu` is telling you that cpu 255 is offline (inactive):

```
On-line CPU(s) list:  0-254
Off-line CPU(s) list: 255
```

You could try to bring it back online by

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu255/online
```

---

After some clarification in the comments, it's evident that to get all CPU's in the latest AMD EPYC processors to work, you need a more recent Linux kernel than the one that ships with older 18.04 LTS releases. According to this [review](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-EPYC-Rome-Linux-5.3-Perf) the minimum recommended kernel is **4.18**. Also make sure you have the latest firmware on your motherboard.

Comment: I tried using the echo command with no luck.   I then tried to edit the file "online" directly using "sudo vi online,"  but I could not save it.   Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I tried chcpu: "sudo chcpu -e 255," but the enable failed because I had an invalid argument.

Comment: I tried using chcpu -c 255, but it is not configurable. Is this a limitation of Ubuntu 18.04?  I noticed that other benchmarks on Geekbench using dual AMD EPYC 7742 cpus are using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: I doubt there is a limit at the kernel level. What do you get if you run `grep CONFIG_NR_CPUS /boot/config-$(uname -r)`?

Comment: Also do you get any message printed in `dmesg` after you execute `echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu255/online`?  What do you get if you do `dmesg | grep smpboot` afterwards?

Comment: The answers are CONFIG_NR_CPUS=8192 and native_cpu_up: bad cpu 255.

Comment: The vendor that put together the machine had this comment: I found some info about this issue is related to this newer AMD CPU (64 Core with 128 Threads).  Basically, it is related to the APIC on the motherboard as the default is a 8bit register (so it can only address 255 device).
It may necessary to enable able the X2APIC mode on the system for the last remaining CPU (#255).  However, the Ubuntu 18.04 may not support the X2APIC mode.   The Ubuntu 19.04 may have a patches that will support the X2APIC mode in the kernel, so that should allow to access the remaining CPU.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, because looking at the source code of smpboot [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c#L1141) it's clear that "bad cpu" most likely means invalid APIC id. So you might need a newer kernel that supports more than 255 APIC ids, which could mean upgrading your kernel to 5.0 or installing 19.04.

Comment: According to [this phronix review](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-EPYC-Rome-Linux-5.3-Perf) `x2apic support was added in 4.18`. So your kernel version should definitely be >= 4.18.

Comment: 18.04.3 has a newer kernel than 4.15. In fact, it should be 5.0.

Comment: I realized that. It's odd. So it's definitely not the kernel version alone that's causing this.

Comment: We are trying some things before upgrading to 19.04.  The vendor recommended to try the following, but it did not work: To enable/ change to X2APIC mode in BIOS:
Boot to BIOS,
Advanced --> CPU  Configuration --> Local APIC Mode --> X2APIC
Then save and reset the system for the change to take effect.
Please note that if the Kernel did not support X2APIC mode, then it may result in kernel panic.  It may necessary to reboot for the change to take effect in BIOS.

Comment: Hope you get this sorted with Supermicro. Do let us know If you manage to resolve it. These CPUs are too new and there may be others who run into this same issue.

Comment: Here is the reply from Supermicro:

This issue is due to that your Linux kernel does not support 256 CPU cores. Make sure that your Linux kernel version is equal to or higher than 4.19x, and enable IOMMU (Input/Output Memory Management Unit) in BIOS.

So, from above: you need OS kernel with 4.19 & above, then enable IOMMU in BIOS setting.

It was implemented as follows: BIOS, Advanced ==>  NB Configuration ==> IOMMU ==> Enabled.   It worked.  The Geekbench 4 score is now near the very top with other dual AMD EPYC 7742 processors.

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to add an answer to your own question outlining what your hardware is and what you did exactly to resolve it. This way future readers will quickly find the solution and not have to read into these comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it running with X2APIC turned on on kernel 4.15.0-72-generic. I guess X2APIC support was backported there.

It wasn't necessary to fiddle with IOMMU.